# ZIO Propagate custom exception family within Future[Either[MyException, A]], without Task which is Throwable only

Tags: scala, zio

I'm looking to try out ZIO but I have an exception family that looks similar to this

```
trait MyException extends Exception {
    def errorCode: Int
}
```

, functions that return `Future[Either[MyException, A]]` and the problem I'm running into is transforming these into ZIO land. e.g.

```
def foo(): Future[Either[MyException, A]] = ???

def process(): ZIO[Any, MyException, Unit] =
  ZIO
    .fromFuture(_ => foo())
    .flatMap(ZIO.fromEither[MyException, Unit]) // compiler error, expects Throwable instead of MyException
```

because I know foo() can return MyException, I want that to reflect in the ZIO type but it appears the type is lost during the transformation

Answer (score 0):

First of all `foo` should take in an `ExecutionContext` so that it can use the one provided by the ZIO runtime instead of any global `ExecutionContext` you might have:

```scala
def foo[A]()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Either[MyException, A]] = ???
```

Because ZIO still expects `Future` to still be able to fail with any `Throwable` and not just `MyException`, either you widen the error of `process` to `Throwable`, like:

```scala
  def process(): ZIO[Any, Throwable, Unit] =
    ZIO
      .fromFuture(implicit ec => foo())
      .flatMap(ZIO.fromEither[MyException, Unit](_)) //`fromEither` takes in an impicit in ZIO 2 so we need to be more explicit with the syntax
```

or you will still need to handle the `Throwable` with a handler like `catchAll`:

```scala
  def process(): ZIO[Any, MyException, Unit] =
    ZIO
      .fromFuture(implicit ec => foo())
      .catchAll {
        //it depends on how you want to handle the `Throwable` as long as you only fail with `MyException`
        case e: MyException => ZIO.fail(e)
        case _ => ZIO.succeed(Right())
      }.flatMap(ZIO.fromEither[MyException, Unit](_))
```

> without Task which is Throwable only

I think you might be confusing the contravariant ZIO environment with the covariant error type parameter. The `process` you want can fail with `MyException` **only** but the lifted `Future` within can fail with **any** `Throwable` including `MyException`. You can read more about variances [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html).